# Excel: Value from one cell based on max value with multiple criteria in other column

Tags: excel, max, criteria, vlookup

I am trying to get value in column 8, based on MAX value (column Range4) with multiple criteria (Range1, Range2, Range3), but excel gives me an error "#N/A". Where is the mistake?

```
VLOOKUP(MAX(IF(Range1=2013;IF(Range2="april";IF(Range3="Alexa";Range4))));Range5;8;FALSE)
```

The part

```
{MAX(IF(Range1=2013;IF(Range2="april";IF(Range3="Alexa";Range4))))}
```

works right alone (it gives me the right value), but not inside the VLOOKUP function.

Thanks!

*Sample data set for testing:*

```
First_day   Last_day    Week_Num    Week_Range  Month   Year    Rank_name   Rank_value
01/04/2013  07/04/2013  14  1-7 april   april   2013    Alexa   10122
08/04/2013  14/04/2013  15  8-14 april  april   2013    Alexa   9670
15/04/2013  21/04/2013  16  15-21 april april   2013    Alexa   9130
22/04/2013  28/04/2013  17  22-28 april april   2013    Alexa   8340
29/04/2013  05/05/2013  18  29-5 april  april   2013    Alexa   7543
31/03/2014  06/04/2014  14  31-06 april april   2014    Alexa   11428
07/04/2014  13/04/2014  15  07-13 april april   2014    Alexa   7159
14/04/2014  20/04/2014  16  14-20 april april   2014    Alexa   7027
21/04/2014  27/04/2014  17  21-27 april april   2014    Alexa   6675
28/04/2014  04/05/2014  18  28-04 april april   2014    Alexa   5379
```

Equivalence between ranges and columns:

- Range1 = Column "Year"
- Range2 = Column "Month"
- Range3 = Column "Rank_name"
- Range4 = Column "Week_Num"
- Range5 = Column "Rank_value"

Comment: Did you enter your VLOOKUP formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter ? It does not look like it. Also, you should provide a value for the "else" part of `IF` calls. It's optionnal but generally a good idea to provide a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(Range8;MATCH(MAX(IF(Range1=2013;IF(Range2="april";IF(Range3="Alexa";Range4))));Range4;0))
```

with Control+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm afraid the formula sometimes does not work right and gives me wrong values. When I have same month values in Range2 and different year values in Range1, excel gives me the Range4 value based on the first value that finds in Range1, disregarding the year criteria. Example: Row 1={2012;april;Alexa;15} and Row 2={2013;april;Alexa;1000}. Then excel gives me "15", instead of "1000". Please help and thanks again.

Comment: How can I share some sample data here? Website does not let me upload screenshot images yet :-(

Comment: I hope the new csv block in Q might help. If anything else is needed please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the existing formula (from pnuts, Jun 10 2014) is this:
The formula first narrows the list down by the nested if's, and then picks the maximum Week_Num from those rows that match your criteria.  But having located that maximum, the MATCH function then ignores the criteria (they were only used to find the max from Range4).  If you have other rows (even though they don't match the criteria) that have the same Week_Num, MATCH will locate the first row out of the whole list that has the same Week_Num in Range4.  One solution is to add the same criteria to the MATCH's "lookup_array" that were used in the "lookup_value".

=INDEX(Range8;MATCH(MAX(IF(Range1=2013;IF(Range2="april";IF(Range3="Alexa";Range4))));IF(Range1=2013;IF(Range2="april";IF(Range3="Alexa";Range4)));0))

Again, using Control-Shift-Enter.

I think I entered the above formula correctly, but I didn't build a sheet to test it, so...

Also, be aware, this formula still has a problem in the case where no rows in the list meet the criteria.  In that case you get an error.  The solution to that is to add an IFERROR at the front of the whole thing.

=IFERROR(INDEX(Range8;MATCH(MAX(IF(Range1=2013;IF(Range2="april";IF(Range3="Alexa";Range4))));IF(Range1=2013;IF(Range2="april";IF(Range3="Alexa";Range4)));0)),"")